# Inconsistent results while querying on a index

Tags: elasticsearch

when I search on field, I get results which used recently and couldn't get results for new words( searching for first time ) .

my query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "textfeild": "lonely"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "feild": 123456
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100
}
```

after full load (aproximate 10 million rec) I face this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is the index growing between your subsequent requests? What do your mappings look like? How many results are you returning vs how many hits are you getting?

Comment: yes index is runing in incremental                                                                  my mapping                                                                                                      "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "ttl": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }